# Speeding up DBSCAN algorithm (from scratch) in Python with Cython or numpy

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, cython, dbscan

I'm new to this stack overflow thing so please forgive any errors. I'm working on a DBSCAN algorithm in python right now and the only problem is that it's pretty slow (the fit_predict() method). I have added Cython optimizations I have heard of but there's only Cython's only 22% faster than python here. If you know Cython please let me know what I could add or what's going wrong and why. I'm also open to just changing the whole algorithm and using more Numpy to speed things up .

'''

```
                import numpy as np
                from libc cimport math
                
                def distance(list x, list y):
                    return np.sqrt(sum([(x_i - y_i) ** 2 for x_i, y_i in zip(x, y)]))
                
                
                cdef int indexOf(list elements, element):
                    cdef int indice = 0
                    try:
                        indice = elements.index(element)
                    except Exception:
                        indice = -1
                    return indice
                
                
                cdef list vector_mean(list vectors):
                    mean = np.zeros(len(vectors[0]))
                    for vector in vectors:
                        mean += np.array(vector)
                    return (mean / len(vectors)).tolist()
                
                
                def  connected_cluster(x_train, core_instances, point, eps):
                    for core_instance in core_instances:
                        yield eventually_connected(x_train, point, core_instance, eps)
                
                
                cdef list find_neighbors(list data, list point, double eps):
                    '''neighbors = []
                    for data_point in data:
                        if data_point == point: continue
                        if distance(data_point, point) <= eps:
                            neighbors.append(data_point)'''
                    neighbors = [data_point for data_point in data if distance(data_point, point) <= eps and data_point != point]
                    return neighbors
                
                
                
                def find_key(dict dictionary, item):
                    item_key = -1
                    for key in dictionary:
                        if indexOf(dictionary[key], item) != - 1: item_key = key
                    return item_key
                
                
                def reg_find_key(dictionary, item):
                    item_key = None
                    for key in dictionary:
                        if dictionary[key] == item: item_key = key
                    return item_key
                
                
                cdef eventually_connected(list data, list core_instance, list other_core_instance, double eps):  # returns True connected else None
                    '''find all neighbors of core_instance, neighbors of neighbors, ... and see if any of them match other core instance'''
                    cdef list neighbors = find_neighbors(data, core_instance, eps)
                    # print("These are neighbors : ", neighbors)
                    if other_core_instance in neighbors:
                        return True
                    else:
                        for neighbor in neighbors:
                            return eventually_connected(remove(data, core_instance), neighbor, other_core_instance, eps)  # remove the starting point
                
                
                cdef list remove(list listy, element):
                    cdef list new_list = []
                    for stuff in listy:
                        if stuff != element:
                            new_list.append(stuff)
                    return new_list
                
                
                def core_instances_connected(list data, list core_instance1, list core_instance2, double eps):
                    # we have the core_instances, find their neighbors
                    cdef list core_instance_neighbors1 = find_neighbors(data, core_instance1, eps)
                    cdef list core_instance_neighbors2 = find_neighbors(data, core_instance2, eps)
                    # we need to see if any points match
                    connected = False
                    for neighbor1 in core_instance_neighbors1:
                        for neighbor2 in core_instance_neighbors2:
                            if neighbor1 == neighbor2:
                                connected = True
                    return connected
                
                
                def core_instances_distance_connected(core_instance1, core_instance2, eps):
                    connected = False
                    if distance(core_instance1, core_instance2) <= 4 * eps:
                        connected = True
                    return connected
                
                
                cdef int count_core_instances_in_cluster(list clusters):
                    cdef int num_core_instances = 0
                    for cluster in clusters:
                        num_core_instances += len(cluster)
                    return num_core_instances
                
                
                import random
                
                
                cdef class DBSCAN :
                    cdef list all_connected_core_instances, not_connected_core_instances, core_instances, original_x_train
                    cdef double eps
                    cdef dict points_to_classes, clusters, visualize_clusters
                
                    def __init__(self):
                        self.all_connected_core_instances = []
                        self.not_connected_core_instances = []
                
                    cpdef list  get_core_instances(self):
                        return self.core_instances
                
                    cpdef find_connections(self, data, starting_core_instance, core_instances, eps):
                        # print("this is data : ", data)
                        # print("this is sci : ", starting_core_instance)
                        cdef list neighbors = find_neighbors(data, starting_core_instance[0], eps)
                        cdef list core_instance_neighbors = []
                        for neighbor in neighbors:
                            if neighbor in core_instances:  # it is a core instance here
                                core_instance_neighbors.append(neighbor)
                                self.all_connected_core_instances.append(neighbor)
                                self.not_connected_core_instances.remove(neighbor)
                        for core_instance_neighbor in core_instance_neighbors:
                            try:
                                DBSCAN.find_connections(self, data.remove(starting_core_instance), core_instance_neighbor,
                                                        core_instances, eps)
                            except Exception:
                                # print("Done find_connections")
                                pass
                
                    cpdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] fit_predict(self, x_train, eps=0.5, min_neighbors=7):
                        try:
                            x_train = x_train.tolist()
                        except Exception:
                            pass
                
                        self.original_x_train = x_train
                        self.eps = eps
                        cdef list core_instances = []
                        cdef dict core_instances_to_indices_points = {}
                        for point in range(len(x_train)):
                            neighbors = find_neighbors(x_train, x_train[point], self.eps)
                            if len(neighbors) >= min_neighbors:
                                core_instances.append(x_train[point])
                                core_instances_to_indices_points[tuple(x_train[point])] = [x_train.index(neighbor) for neighbor in
                                                                                           neighbors]  # contains the indices for the points that belong to a core_instance
                
                        # what do we do with the noisy points - nothing right?
                        print("LEN CORE INSTANCES : ", len(core_instances))
                        print("core_instances_to_indices_points : ", core_instances_to_indices_points)
                        self.core_instances = core_instances
                
                        # now we merge the clusters
                        cdef list connected_core_instances = []
                        cdef clusters = {label_idx: [core_instance] for label_idx, core_instance in enumerate(core_instances)}
                
                        # todo optimize here - merge cluster process is slowest rn - its just the first iteration!!!! - > do we need to go through all core_instances in core_instances
                
                        for core_instance in core_instances: #todo add tqdm loop over here
                            if core_instance in connected_core_instances:
                                print("skipping c_i")
                                continue
                            for other_core_instance in core_instances:
                                if other_core_instance in connected_core_instances:
                                    print('skipping o_ci')
                                    continue
                
                                if eventually_connected(x_train, core_instance, other_core_instance,
                                                        self.eps):  # TODO EVENTUALLY CONNECTED AS WELL
                                    print("Found connected!!")
                                    del clusters[reg_find_key(clusters, [other_core_instance])]  # delete the other_core_instance cluster
                                    clusters[find_key(clusters, core_instance)].append(
                                        other_core_instance)  # whichever cluster has the core_instance shall have the other core instance now
                                    add_indices = core_instances_to_indices_points[tuple(other_core_instance)]
                                    del core_instances_to_indices_points[tuple(other_core_instance)]
                                    core_instances_to_indices_points[tuple(core_instance)] += add_indices
                                    connected_core_instances.append(
                                        other_core_instance)  # TODO THESE ARE THE MAKE OR BREAKS, WHEN YOU STOP!
                                    print("did what had to be done : ")
                            connected_core_instances.append(core_instance)
                
                
                        print('this is connected_core_instances : ', connected_core_instances)
                
                        print("CTIP : ", core_instances_to_indices_points)
                
                        self.visualize_clusters = {}  # put labels back into 0s and 1s
                
                        cdef double curr_lbl = 0.0
                        for index, cluster in clusters.items():
                            self.visualize_clusters[curr_lbl] = cluster
                            curr_lbl += 1.0
                
                        cdef dict new_clusters = {}
                        for label, cluster in clusters.items():
                            new_cluster = []
                            for c_i in cluster:
                                print(c_i, tuple(c_i) in list(core_instances_to_indices_points.keys()))
                                if tuple(c_i) in list(core_instances_to_indices_points.keys()):
                                    new_cluster.append(c_i)
                            new_clusters[label] = new_cluster
                
                        self.clusters = {}
                        for index, cluster in new_clusters.items():
                            self.clusters[curr_lbl] = cluster
                            curr_lbl += 1.0
                
                        # remove any core instances that aren't a part of the merged cluster
                
                        print("Cluster : ", self.clusters)
                        print("Len : ", len(self.clusters))
                        print("LEN CITP : ", len(core_instances_to_indices_points))
                        print("CITP : ", core_instances_to_indices_points)
                
                        cdef dict predictions_dict = {} #todo this is the problem with repeats in the core instances!
                        cdef dict points_to_classes = {} #tuple(point) : label
                        for label, cluster in self.clusters.items():
                            '''cluster is a collection of core_instances, each with their own indices of the data points'''
                            current_prediction_indices = []
                            print(core_instances_to_indices_points)
                            for core_instance in cluster:
                                current_prediction_indices += core_instances_to_indices_points[tuple(core_instance)]
                                points_to_classes[tuple(core_instance)] = label #also make sure that this is here
                            predictions_dict[label] = current_prediction_indices
                        print("predictions_dict : ", predictions_dict)
                
                        predictions = [-1] * len(x_train)
                        for label, indices in predictions_dict.items():
                            for indice in indices:
                                predictions[indice] = label
                                points_to_classes[tuple(x_train[indice])] = label
                
                        print("eliminating repeats!")
                        print('this is points_to_classes : ', points_to_classes)
                        #make sure repeats don't get the -1s
                        for point in range(len(x_train)) :
                            try :
                                #assuming not noise!
                                predictions[point] = points_to_classes[tuple(x_train[point])]
                            except Exception : pass
                        self.points_to_classes = points_to_classes
                        return np.array(predictions).flatten()
                
                    cpdef dict get_clusters(self):
                        return self.clusters
```

'''
Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: I'd guess that your file is called "something.py"? Cython only accepts it's extended syntax in ".pyx" files and requires normal Python syntax in ".py" files.

Comment: Thanks for your response DavidW!!! I have put this in a .pyx file and compiled in a setup.py file. Maybe the file type is looking different from my perspective than yours. If it was in a .py file it wouldn't work because things like "cdef" wouldn't be recognized. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - right. Given your vague description of the error message I thought that the `cdef`s might be what it's going wrong on. You have an indentation error at `def find()`. It's a big chunk of code to look at so I doubt I'll be able to say anything more specific